# Automation of the new Gmail login using sahi

Tags: authentication, automation, gmail, sahi

I am using sahi pro web ui automation tool and hit an issue with automating the login to gmail. I was able to automate the older version using setValue in username and password but the new version of gmail login now has two parts, first enter the user name, click next and then enter password to login. I am unable to click on the next on the first screen. Did anyone had any luck in automating the new gmail login via sahi?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the login form on https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail ?
The Sahi Controller identifies the button with `_submit("Next")` and `_click(_submit("Next"));` works for me

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant and for me the sahi controller does identify the next button but the click action doesnt take me to the next screen to enter the password. Do you think there is any setting in sahi that I need to configure?

Comment: I can just guess... SSL related maybe? http://community.sahipro.com/forums/discussion/4744/how-to-use-sahi-with-gmail/p1

Comment: I just checked, its not the SSL configuration. As I mentioned in the post this was working fine untill google changed the login process to two step instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps given below to get it fixed on your machine:

1. Click on Configure link on the Sahi Dashboard.
2. Click on the `donot_download_urls.txt` link on the left side of the page that opens up.
3. The file will open up in the editor on the right.
4. Add the following line in the file:
   `.*accountLoginInfoXhr.*`
5. Save the file.
6. Restart Sahi and try out your test again.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try clicking again, it works for me! If the function below doesn' t do the trick, then replace _click() with _doubleClick():

```
function stressClick(){
    if(_isVisible(_submit("Next"))){
        _click(_submit("Next"));
        stressClick();
    }
}
```